# Activity UI state is kept after screen orientation

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I know that every time when configuration changes (i.e. screen orientation) Activity is destroyed and restarted.

However I experience a weird scenario in which UI state is recovered even if I didn't save the state at onSaveInstanceState and did not specify android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" at the Activity's manifest. Also I didnt bother to override onRetainNonConfigurationInstance.

Example I check a checkbox or entered a value to a TextView. When I change orientation the values are still there. (I didnt save them to the database yet)

Am I missing something?

Update:By the way Im using SherlockActivity... would that matter

Comment: Are you using Fragments? If I'm not mistaken, Fragments save their state automatically now. (I could totally be mistaken) ((I seem to definitely be mistaken :) ))

Comment: Could those view be auto-populating from another field, an api call, a shared preference?  Post some code for us.

Comment: @kcoppock no, Fragments get killed with the activity.

Comment: @cybler no api call, no shared preference, they will only be populated from the database. The flow is like this 1.) layout is assigned 2.) initialize UI from the database 3.) enter values to checkbox or textview 4.) change orientation 5.) changes are there even if I didnt save it yet (note i didnt override onStop and onResume either In fact manually destroying the Activity by pressing Back button and launching it again will not display the changes)...

Comment: Sorry guys i didnt specify that Im using SherlockActivity... would that matter?